# When is an object completely defined?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and want to define 2 classes inside an object. The second class is derived from the first class.

It looks like:

```js
let foo = {
    bar: (function () {
        let bar_msg = '';

        class bar {
            constructor(msg) {
                bar_msg = msg;
            }
        }
        return bar;
    }()),
    baz: (function () {
        let baz_msg = '';

        class baz extends foo.bar {
            constructor(msg) {
                super();
                baz_msg = msg;
            }
        }
        return baz;
    }())
};
```

Error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined

Then, I've tried to split the classes to multiple parts:

```js
let foo = {};

foo.bar = (function () {
    let bar_msg = '';

    class bar {
        constructor(msg) {
            bar_msg = msg;
        }
    }
    return bar;
}());

foo.baz = (function () {
    let baz_msg = '';

    class baz extends foo.bar {
        constructor(msg) {
            super();
            baz_msg = msg;
        }
        msg() {
            return baz_msg;
        }
    }
    return baz;
}());

let b = new foo.baz('hi!');
console.log(b.msg());
```

It works.

So, my question is: Why do I get the difference? I cannot show some google search results because I have no idea about the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

An object is 'completely' defined when you declared it and assign it a value like so:

```
var foo = 'bar';
```

You may declare a variable but not assign it to any value:

```
var foo;
```

and when you try to access it, it will give you undefined. You may also assign a value to an undeclared variable:

```
foo = 'bar';
```

And the javascript will automatically create a global variable `foo`. If you try to access a variable that has never been declared or implicitly declared (e.g `foo = 'bar'`). It will throw an error;

```
console.log(iDoNotExist); // will throw an error!
```

In your first code, the class baz, could not locate `foo` in its own scope, so it will go to the global scope. But since it's also not available in the global scope and it has neither been declared explicitly nor implicitly, it will throw an error.

In the second code, you have explicitly declared `foo` and assign it to an object and added a property `bar` right after it. Any code written after `foo` is declared would be able to access it, including when you assign the property `bar` to `foo`, in which a class called `baz` tries to extend `foo.bar`. If the piece of code that tries to extend `foo` or `foo.bar` is written after the definition of `foo`. It will throw an error. See snippet below for example:

```js
class baz extends foo {
        constructor(msg) {
            super();
            baz_msg = msg;
        }
        msg() {
            return baz_msg;
        }
    }

let foo = {};

let b = new foo.baz('hi!');
```

In summary, you get the difference because the accessibility of `foo`. In the first variable you try to access it before it is both neither explicitly nor implicitly defined, resulting in an error. In the second variable, you've declared and assigned it to a value and try to access it after, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: I think it's not enough information. Because I've just tested again with code: `let foo = { bar() { console.log(typeof foo); } };`. When I called `foo.bar()`, it logged: `object`. So, your answer went wrong

Comment: did you call foo.bar outside of the declaration of `foo` or inside? Try calling the bar function within foo. You will get undefined, the same case when you try to extend the class `baz` with `foo`, which has yet to be available as it has not been declared yet.